# Embedding React or React Native to an existing mobile app

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have been doing research about usability scenarios of React and React Native to ultimately decide whether it is a feasible and responsible decision to embed React (or React Native) to an existing mobile app.

So far, what I have learned is that it is possible to render React Native code within a custom view in both Android and iOS. Embedding React is simpler, since a React app is literally a web page that loads the client side framework.

My concerns are many and may also be pointless if I misinterpreted some scenarios. Below are the ones for which my Google skills failed me to get some answers.

1. Is it possible to use a third party's React component in a React Native rendering view?
2. What do I lose in terms of backward compatibility and UI performance to fully utilize React Native in mobile? Do low-end devices handle it well?
3. Is debugging React and React Native a pain? This question may and should be responded subjectively.
4. When I use React Native, is it possible to push updates to my app's that specific part without publishing an update to Google Play or Apple App Store?
5. Is React or React Native incompatible with CoffeeScript on the server side? If so, can I avoid that with a custom build flow to ultimately end up with only Javascript files which contain all the server code?

Sorry for the long entry.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked for react native for several months，and here is my answer:

> Is it possible to use a third party's React component in a React Native rendering view?

No,react component for Browser cannot use for mobile.but there are many mobile specific component.You can find here:[React.parts](https://react.parts/native)

> What do I lose in terms of backward compatibility and UI performance to fully utilize React Native in mobile? Do low-end devices handle it well?

You can test [these apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html) on low-end devices to see whether react native can meet your need.

> Is debugging React and React Native a pain? This question may and should be responded subjectively.

No,debug React Native code is really easy and efficient.

> When I use React Native, is it possible to push updates to my app's that specific part without publishing an update to Google Play or Apple App Store?

Yes,you can do these things easily with [Code Push](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push).

> Is React or React Native incompatible with CoffeeScript on the server side? If so, can I avoid that with a custom build flow to ultimately end up with only Javascript files which contain all the server code?

There isn't server side code in React Native,all your js code is in a single js file called bundle.js. the compile process is automatic with packager.sh witch provided from React Native,check this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/packager).